# vb.net Impersonate Webbrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, impersonation

I need to impersonate the WinForms Webbrowser Control. For impersonating I'm using the AliasAccount class from here: [Open remote shared folder with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559867/open-remote-shared-folder-with-credentials)

It works great but not with the WebBrowser control.

Dim aa As New AliasAccount(DomainName & "\" & UserName, mypassword)

```
Dim aa As New AliasAccount(DomainName & "\" & UserName, mypassword)

aa.BeginImpersonation()

Dim webImp As New WebBrowser
webImp.Height = 220
webImp.Width = 220
webImp.Location = New Point(390, 208)
webImp.Navigate("http://www.google.com")

Me.Controls.Add(webImp)
aa.EndImpersonation()
```

I see the control in my form but the webImp.Navigate("www.google.ch") does not work! I don't know why. Does somebody have an idea?

If I check the ReadyState of the Webbrowser:

```
Do While wbImp.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop
```

It never stops. It's keeping in the loop.

Comment: I tried also to navigate after adding the control, but same result.

Comment: Does it work if you take out the impersonation part?

Comment: thx for comment, yes, if i remove aa.BeginImpersonation() it works properly