# C# Webbrowser Control impersonation

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, impersonation

I need to impersonate the WinForms Webbrowser Control. For impersonating I'm using the AliasAccount class from here: [Open remote shared folder with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559867/open-remote-shared-folder-with-credentials)

It works great but not with the WebBrowser control.

```
AliasAccount aa = new AliasAccount(DomainName + "\\" + UserName, mypassword);

    aa.BeginImpersonation();

    WebBrowser webImp = new WebBrowser();
    webImp.Height = 220;
    webImp.Width = 220;
    webImp.Location = new Point(390, 208);
    webImp.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

    this.Controls.Add(webImp);
    aa.EndImpersonation();
```

I see the control in my form but the webImp.Navigate("www.google.ch") does not work! I don't know why. Does somebody have an idea?

If I check the ReadyState of the Webbrowser:

```
while (wbImp.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

It never stops. It's keeping in the loop.